# Superfluous epimorphisms maps maximal submodules into maximal submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

We define a **superfluous epimorphism**, $f:P \to M$, if $f$ is a module epimorphism and $\ker(f)  \leq P$  is superfluous, that means that if there is $P_{1} \leq P$ such $P_{1} + \ker(f)=P$ then $P_{1}=P$. I want to prove that if there is a maximal submodule $Q \leq P$ then $f(Q)$ is a maximal submodule of $M$. Let say we have $N \leq M$ such $f(Q) \subseteq N \subseteq M$. I want to show that $N=f(Q)$ or $N=M$ so we proceed by supposing both cases. So I got lost around using the preimages to prove this, also don't know how to use the hypothesis of $\ker(f)$ superfluous on $P$. Thanks.

Comment: Try using $P_1=f^{-1}(N)$.

Comment: Got it! Let $ f(Q) \subseteq N \subseteq M$ and $f^{-1}(N)=P_{1}$ then $f(f^{-1}(N))=N=f(P_{1})=f(P)=M$ so $N=M$ and we are done right? But why we got $P_{1}=f^{-1}(N)$?? :\ @Mohan